# Bulk import + export url rerwrites for Magento

Tags: magento, redirect, bulk, google-search-console

I found a "bulk import and export url rewrites extension" for Magento when looking on the internet on how to bulk redirect urls from my current live site to the new urls based on the new site which is on a development server still.

I’ve asked my programmer to help me out and they’ve sent me 2 CSV files, one with all request and target urls from the current live site (these are often different as well, probably due to earlier redirects), and one similar to that for the new site. The current live site comes with 2500 urls, the future site with 3500 (probably because some old, inactive and unnecessary categories are still in the new site as well).

I was thinking to paste the current site’s urls into an Excel sheet and to then insert the future urls per url. A lot of work… Then I thought: can’t I limit my work to the approx. 300 urls that Google has indexed (which can be found through Google Webmaster Tools as you probably know)?

What would you recommend? Would there be advantages to using such an extension? Which advantages would that be? (if you keep in mind that my programmer would upload all of my redirects into a .htaccess file for me?)

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards, Bob.

Comment: This is more of an advise question, than a technical question.  It's really up to you to decided whether or not you want your old links to redirect to your new ones.  I personally don't bother with doing so in site conversions.  I just resubmit a sitemap.xml file to Google (generated from Magento), and hope that Google replaces out the old links with the new ones in a timely manner.  If you rely on those previous links to drive traffic, then I would probably look for a mapping solution to get the user to the correct URL.

Answer (score 4):

Axel is giving HORRIBLE advice.. 301 redirects tell Google to transfer old PR and authority of that page to the new page in the redirect.. More over if other websites linked to those pages you don't want a bunch of dead links, then someone MIGHT just remove them.

Even worse if you don't handle the 404's correctly Google can and will penalize you.

ALWAYS setup 301 redirects when changing platforms, only someone that either doesn't understand or perhaps care about SEO would suggest otherwise